# Error: The shape of dict['input'] provided in model.execute(dict) must be [-1,128,128,3], but was [-1,128,128,3] in Tensorflow JS

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am running a simple benchmarking application with tensorflow js. Running into this very weird errors.

I create my input shape `input_shape = model.inputs[0].shape`

and then create a zeros array as dummy input to the model `var zeros = tf.zeros([input_shape]);`

and then calling `await timeModelInference(model, zeros, 1)` yields the error in the title.

```
util_base.js:153 Uncaught (in promise) Error: The shape of dict['input'] provided in model.execute(dict) must be [-1,128,128,3], but was [-1,128,128,3]
    at Vv (util_base.js:153)
    at graph_executor.js:572
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at e.t.checkInputShapeAndType (graph_executor.js:563)
    at e.<anonymous> (graph_executor.js:345)
    at c (runtime.js:63)
    at Generator._invoke (runtime.js:293)
    at Generator.next (runtime.js:118)
    at bv (runtime.js:747)
    at o (runtime.js:747)
```

I've tried changing the first dimension to [1,128,128,3] or [,128,128,3] to no avail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging this for a bit, the problem was that i was calling `tf.zeros([input_shape])` instead of `tf.zeros(input_shape)` This extra wrapping of arrays caused the problem even though the shapes were exactly the same. Better be more careful next time. :)